# How do I share a file from iOS?

Tags: ios, itunes, file-sharing

I am writing an app for hikers that creates a GPS track (much like GaiaGPS, etc., but better) but for the life of me I can't get my hands on the the GPX file that it creates. I have enabled iTunes file sharing and everything works fine on the Simulator but when I run the app on my iPhone Xr and save the file and then hook the phone up to my iMac there is no mention of my app on the "Files" tab in the Finder window for the phone.

I am not in love with this type of sharing; I would be happy with ANY solution that gets my data onto the iMac.

Does the app have to be registered in some way that I haven't heard about?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] and review [ask]. First step should be normal searching... I went to google and searched for `swift ios save data to file and share`  and immediately found this [How to Integrate Your App with Files App in iOS 11](https://www.appcoda.com/files-app-integration/) (which looks like it could be very helpful).

Comment: Thanks, That looks like it might help. I had searched Google and Apple Docs and anywhere else I could find; I used, at various times, all the words in your query but I never hit that magic combination.

Comment: All is well. The only thing that wasn't working was the iTunes connection. When the document you sent me showed me how to use the Files app properly my files was just sitting there waiting for me! iTunes deserved to die :-)

Comment: To add insult to injury, my files appeared in iTunes this evening, as if by magic.